# Http Requests and Data Packets

Tags: http

During an http request, what determines the number and size of data packets for the response? Does this depend upon the Accept header?

For example, would a request for application/json result in a single data packet provided that the data is less than some maximum size, while a request for an application/octet-stream result in multiple packets?

edit: I am particularly interested in the number of data packets chosen and how it is chosen. The possible duplicate question linked makes no mention of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

Comment: Edited question with reasons why it is not a duplicate.